# Why the router.go() does not work in Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue-router, vue.js

Using vue-router, I have a component check user login status, how can I redirect to the login page URL using the router?

In component, my code:

```
<script>
  export default {
    components: {
    },
   
    name: 'landing-page',
    created: function () {
      const router = this.$router
      router.go({path: '/login'})
    }
  }
</script>
```

But `router.go` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that `router.go` takes a single integer parameter that indicates by how many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack. So to give a path you should use `router.push('your_url')`.

For more information I suggest you read this:
[Vuerouter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Answer (score 5):

Oh, use `router.push('/login')` can working fine.

Comment: To be a good answer this needs an explanation.